# Approach for server discovery / polling on same network

Tags: java, sockets, server, network-programming, polling

I am writing Java program and I am creating multiple servers, each of them able to connect to multiple clients with threads.

I am looking to make each of them know of the existence of the other, and periodically check if a server has died or a new server has started, with the purpose of storing these in a list (each server has a list of all other servers on the network) and creating a small network.

What are some good approaches to tackling this?

Comment: The servers should subscribe to a multicast group, the a multicast message can be sent to the group, and each recipient can reply with its unicast address.